# 'array' is unavailable: please construct an Array from your lazy sequence: Array(...)*

Tags: swift

Yes there are other SO answers for the same error. But I cannot find a case that represents mine closely enough for me to figure it out. Please help.

These lines aren't related. They are in separate blocks. However they are giving the same error.

*'array' is unavailable: please construct an Array from your lazy sequence: Array(...)*

EDIT: These fixed thanks to Vadian. Correct code posted for whoever drops by :)

```
    //let recordDic = YALCity.defaultContent().values.array[selectedIndexPath.row] // re-written
    let recordArray = Array(YALCity.defaultContent().values)
    let recordDic = recordArray[selectedIndexPath.row]

    //let cityName = YALCity.defaultContent().keys.array[indexPath.row] // re-written
    let cityArray = Array(YALCity.defaultContent().keys)
    let cityName = cityArray[indexPath.row]
```

Fixed this one.

```
    // for element in recordDic.keys.array { // error
    for element in Array(recordDic.keys) // fixed :)
```

Still can't get this one.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return YALCity.defaultContent().keys.array.count
    } // error
```

OMG I got it!

```
return Array(YALCity.defaultContent().keys).count
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message says that you cannot use `array` as a property. The suggested syntax is

```
let cityArray = Array(YALCity.defaultContent().keys)
let cityName = cityArray[indexPath.row]
```